# MS Access can see item in the watch window but error thrown saying "item not found in this collection"

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, dao, recordset

Trying to assign a value from one DAO recordet to another. And getting error 3265 "Item not found in this collection". However when i look in the watch window the collection item and value is available. Am I not using the correct syntax here?

So the 'Select' involved in the 'rs' grabs a query statement from the database
the query is executed in rs2 and the the first field should be posted back into the first recordset

```
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
Do Until rs.EOF = True

     qry = rs!Query

     'process the query
     Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(qry)
     If Not (rs2.EOF And rs2.BOF) Then
        rs2.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs2.EOF = True
            rs!NewValue = rs2.Fields(1).value

            rs2.MoveNext

            DoEvents

        Loop
     End If
...
```

When I look in the watch window under rs2.Fields, Count=1 and and 'Item 1' has the value expected. However as with the code execution if I look at rs2.Field(1) it reports "Item not found in this collection."

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in recordsets are indexed from 0. Try this:

```
rs!NewValue = rs2.Fields(0).value
```